# Getting qmake.exe for building Qt with MS VS 2013

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2013, qmake

I tried to build Qt with Visual Studio 12.0 compliler (MS VS 2013) using [this manual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080406/qt-creator-2-8-1-msvc-2013-express-no-compiler-can-produce-code-for-this-qt/21098069#21098069)

Currently i am on this step:

```
> configure -developer-build -opensource -confirm-license -nomake examples -nomake tests -opengl desktop
```

As far as I can see from console output, it tries to build a qmake.exe in qtbase directory.
Here is a pic from console:

[image]

Last error in Russian means that there is no qmake.exe in this directory.
So, how do i get it and what possible reasons for its absence?
I have installed Qt wth MinGW before and there is a qmake.exe there, but i am not sure if it can be used in this case.

Comment: Have you checked whether `C:\Coding\Qt+VS13\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe` actually exists? I mean, is the problem that it is actually not present, or just that `configure` can't find it?

Comment: @Oktalist No, qmake.exe doesn't exist in that folder, the problem is that all content there is downloaded from Git or auto-created during `configure` working. So i guess that is must be there as fas as some lines in console output says `creating qmake`. Should I manually add qmake there? And if yes, what version should be used?

Comment: `configure` is supposed to compile `qmake` itself, so I don't know what the problem could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know after the build of qmake.exe it is copyed to the bin folder from qmake folder. 
Can the Problem be the "+" in your Path? Try to search for the qmake.exe in Qt+Vs13 folder.

Answer (score 3):

just remove the "+" from your directory name